# Feathers js upload file using raw json in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

How do we configure feathers js to support form-data ? . Basically my current implementation right now supports raw json , but I  have a feature
where I have to upload file to amazon bucket and the only way to upload the file like using postman is to support form-data . Thanks

[image]

or like is there a way we can  upload file without using form-data ? like using raw in post-man ? (edited)

Answer (score 0):

For those kinds of file-uploads you need an additional middleware to handle the `multipart/form-data` upload - usually [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is used. Here's some sample code that should help you get started:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const fileUploadHandler = multer();

// Upload Service with multipart support
app.use('/photos',    
    // you can define different storage options, the default is to keep the uploaded data in memory
    fileUploadHandler.single('filename'),
    function(req,res,next){
        // the uploaded file is accessible now under req.file
        next();
    }
);
```